# JAXB: Generating "group" and "attributeGroup" as interface declarations

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to achieve some advanced Java source generation from XSD with JAXB/XJC. What I want do to is the following:
"group" and "attributeGroup" declarations, in a Java context, can be seen as "interface" declarations: They prescribe a specific set of features supported by a type referencing the "group" or "attributeGroup".
I am now looking for a way to automatically generate an interface declaration for each "group"/"attributeGroup" and at the same time generate interface implementation declarations on the respective generated classes.
Is there a plug-in or setting in XJC to achieve this? Is there any other solution to this scenario you know of?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, now to answer my own question, I have created my own jaxb / xjc plugin to perform this task. It is hosted on GitHub:

https://github.com/mklemm/jaxb2-rich-contract-plugin

Comment: Looks like the correct URL is https://github.com/mklemm/jaxb2-rich-contract-plugin

Comment: Yes, you're right ... The other one is outdated now.

Comment: Found your plugin, exactly for needs described in question. But I have lots of: "No interface found for model group" mistakes in log, can you give my any tips on how to overcome them?

Comment: Did you activate the "group-contract" plugin? If not, it should be no problem to just ignore the messages.

Comment: Yes, I activated it by "-Xgroup-contract", without activation everything is fine, but without interfaces. And I can't ignore messages because generation is failed too.

Comment: Hi Danny, I think it would be best to enter a bug report on the project page along  with a code example. I will have a look at it immediately.

Comment: There is an issue currently with <include> of other schema files, if the included schema files have no "targetNamespace" defined. Maybe you should have a look at your included files and add the correct targetNamespace attribute. I'm currently working on a solution that will also work in cases where the targetNamespace isn't specified.